# I want to generate unique ids while inserting into Bigquery table.

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to generate unique ids while inserting into Bigquery table. ROW_NUMBER()OVER() fails with resources exceeded. Forums recommend using ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY). Unfortunately, partition by can't be used as it may produce same row_numbers for the partition by key. Please note that the data that I am trying to insert is at least few hundreds of millions every day.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, partition by can't be used as it may produce same row_numbers for the partition by key

yes - you will get same numbers for different partitions - so you can just use compound key like in below **much simplified example** - just to show approach - you should be able to tweak it to your specific case

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT value, CAST(10*RAND() AS INT64) partitionid
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) value
)
SELECT 
  partitionid, 
  value,
  CONCAT(
    CAST(1000 + partitionid AS STRING), 
    CAST(10000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY partitionid ORDER BY value) AS STRING)
  ) id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY id
```

Comment: INSERT INTO Sampledata.yelp_review_out_rnum (review_id, review_stars, review_date, 
business_id, name, user_id, user_name, AcceptsInsurance) 
SELECT 
row_number()over() AS review_id, t1.stars AS review_stars, t1.review_date, t2.business_id, t2.name, 
t3.user_id, t3.name AS user_name, t4.AcceptsInsurance
FROM Sampledata.yelp_review_medium AS t1 
JOIN Sampledata.yelp_business AS t2 ON t2.business_id=t1.business_id 
JOIN Sampledata.yelp_user AS t3 ON t3.user_id=t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN Sampledata.yelp_business_attributes AS t4 ON t4.business_id=t1.business_id

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above insert statement has to be run every day and review_id in the above insert has to be a unique integer in the table. Does the approach you suggested work in this case? If yes, could you pls explain? Thanks